# ASP.Net Ajax Performance comparisons

Tags: asp.net-ajax

Is there any information showing the performance differences (primarily number of bytes sent and received) between these three ways of sending and receiving data without a full postback: 
 
UpdatePanel
PageMethod
Web Service

By Web Service I mean calling a method within a Web Service from javascript similar to the way you would call a PageMethod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This MSDN Magazine article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163363.aspx) has a lot of the answers I think you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks sliderhouserules.  That is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I read this article when it was published, and wasn't using AJAX at the time, but filed it away in my head as "very valuable info to be used in the future". :)